# Unable to set Time on rooted device with android ICS

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, alarmmanager, rooted-device

I have implemented code for setting time on a rooted device in android.I have made it an in-built app and it works fine in the sample application.But when I tried to use the same code into my application which is also in-built it is NOT able to set the time.
Below is the code

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.setTime(date.getTime());
```

with the permissions....

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_TIME"></uses-permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_TIME_ZONE"></uses-permission>
```

Instead it gives the following error:

```
"Neither user 10042 nor current process has SecurityException:android.permission.SET_TIME
unable to open Alarm Driver:Permission Denied.
android.OS.Parcel.readException
android.app.AlarmManagerStubProxy.setTime(AlarmManager.java)".
```

Any advice would help.